# Closures break induction in correctness proof of interpreter

Tags: lambda-calculus, correctness-proof, software-verification, interpreters

I'm trying to prove the correctness of an interpreter for a simple extension of untyped lambda-calculus with De Bruijn indices. The interpreter is *bounded*, i.e. in order to ensure its finiteness it has an additional parameter $n \in \mathbb N$ that decreases with each recursive call. The function returns $\bot$ when $n = 0$.

This is the signature of the interpreter: $\mathcal E : (\mathbb N, Env, E) \to (Val \cup \{\bot\})$

Where $Env$ is the set of environments, represented as lists of values accessed with De Bruijn indices, $E$ is the set of expressions and $Val$ is the set of values:

$$ \begin{aligned}
  E &::= \lambda E \mid EE \mid A \mid B \mid \texttt{if } E \texttt{ then } E \texttt{ else } E \mid x \in Var \mid V\\
  A &::= \textit{integer operations...}  \\
  B &::= \textit{boolean operations...}  \\
  V &::= \texttt{True} \mid \texttt{False} \mid c \in \mathbb Z \mid \texttt{Closure} (\rho, E)
\end{aligned} $$

##### Soundness theorem

$$\forall e, \rho, n, v . \mathcal E (n, \rho, e) = v \implies \langle e, \rho \rangle \to^* v$$

I.e.: If $e$ evaluates to $v$ under the initial environment $\rho$ and in a finite number of steps, then there exists a finite proof that it does, which uses the rules of the small-step semantics I describe in the "appendix" of this post.

##### Proof Attempt Sketch

I tried to prove the theorem by induction on $e$.

###### Base Cases

The base cases are lambdas, values and variables. I managed to prove these cases with ease.

- **Lambdas**: Let $e = \lambda e'$. First off, the case in which $n = 0$ can be eliminated, since it makes the premise of the theorem false (ex falso...). If $n = Sm$, by the definition of the interpreter we get that the value $v$ must be $\texttt{Closure}(\rho, e')$. The case can be shown to work by applying the LAMBDA rule, some properties of the star closure and the VALUE rule.
- **Values**: trivial.
- **Variables**: Use rule VAR-KO to eliminate the case in which the variable is not in the environment. Then, it's a matter of applying the VAR-OK rule and the definition of the interpreter, plus some property of the star closure.

###### Inductive cases (problem is here!!!)

The most complex inductive case, and the one that is giving me problems, is the case of application: $e = e_1e_2$.
The inductive HPs are:
$$  \forall \rho, n, v . \mathcal E (n, \rho, e_1) = v \implies \langle e_1, \rho \rangle \to^* v \quad \text{(IHe1)} $$
$$  \forall \rho, n, v . \mathcal E (n, \rho, e_2) = v \implies \langle e_2, \rho \rangle \to^* v \quad \text{(IHe2)} $$

By applying these to the definition of $\mathcal E$ and doing some case checking (the evaluations of $e_1$ and $e_2$ cannot be $\bot$ by Hp), from the inductive hypotheses we obtain that for some $\rho'$ and $e'$:

$$ \forall \rho, n \langle e_1, \rho \rangle \to^* \texttt{Closure}(\rho', e') $$

and for some $v'$:

$$ \forall \rho, n, \langle e_2, \rho \rangle \to^* v' $$

At this point we use an auxiliary lemma:

> If $\langle e_1, \rho \rangle \to^* \texttt{Closure}(\rho', e')$ and $\langle e_2, \rho \rangle \to^* v'$, then:
> $$ \langle e_1e_2, \rho\rangle \to^* \langle \texttt{Closure}(\rho', e') v', \rho\rangle$$

Which is easily shown by induction.

We thus obtain:
$$  \langle e_1e_2, \rho\rangle \to^* \langle e', \texttt{bind} (\rho', v') \rangle $$
and:
$$ \mathcal E (S m, \rho, e_1e_2) = \mathcal E (m, \texttt{bind}(\rho', v'), e') = v $$

But we have no induction hypothesis on $e'$, of the form:

$$ \forall \rho, n, v . \mathcal E(n, \rho, e') = v \implies \langle e', \rho \rangle \to^* v \quad \text{(Fake-Hp)} $$

which would allow us to conclude the proof. Do you have any suggestions on how I should finish the proof I sketched in this post?

#### Appendix: Interpreter definition and semantics

What follows is a partial definition of the interpreter (leaving out the non-relevant portions..)

$$ \begin{aligned}
\mathcal E (0, \_, \_) &:= \bot\\
\mathcal E (S n, \rho, \lambda e) &:= \texttt{Closure}(\rho, e)\\
\mathcal E (S n, \rho, v) &:= v &\text{$v \in Val$}\\
\mathcal E (S n, \rho, e_1e_2) &:= \begin{cases}
                                  \mathcal E (n, \texttt{bind}(\rho', \mathcal E(n, \rho, e_2)), e) & \text{if } \mathcal E (n, \rho, e_1) = \texttt{Closure}(\rho', e) \\
                                  \bot &\text{otherwise}
                                 \end{cases}
\\
\mathcal E (S n, \rho, x) &:= \begin{cases}
\mathcal E (n, \rho, \rho[x]) & \text{if $\rho[x] \neq \bot$}\\
\bot & \text{otherwise}
                            \end{cases}
 &\text{$x \in Var$}\\
\end{aligned} $$
Now for the small-step semantics: The intermediate values of the computation have form $\langle e, \rho \rangle$ where $\rho$ is the environment of evaluation. The termination values are the elements of the set $V' = V \cup\{\bot\}$, where $$V = \{\texttt{True}, \texttt{False}, \texttt{Closure}(e, \rho), c \in \mathbb Z\}$$

- Law for transforming lambdas into closures
  $$ \dfrac{}{\langle \lambda e, \rho \rangle \to \langle \texttt{Closure} (\rho, e), \rho \rangle}\label{redlambda} \quad \text{(LAMBDA)}$$
- For all values $v \in Val$:
  $$ \dfrac{}{\langle v, \rho \rangle \to v} \quad \text{(VALUE)}$$
- Laws for variables:
  $$ \dfrac {\rho[x] = v}{\langle x, \rho \rangle \to v} \quad \text{(VAR-OK)} $$
  $$ \dfrac {\rho[x] = \bot}{\langle x, \rho \rangle \to \bot} \quad \text{(VAR-KO)} $$
- Laws for application:
  $$ \dfrac{\langle e_1 , \rho \rangle \to \langle e_1' , \rho \rangle} {\langle e_1 e_2, \rho \rangle \to \langle e_1' e_2, \rho \rangle}\quad\text{(APPLY-1)}$$

$$ \dfrac{\langle e_2, \rho \rangle \to \langle e_2', \rho \rangle} {\langle v_1 e_2, \rho \rangle \to \langle v_1 e_2', \rho \rangle}\quad\text{(APPLY-2)}$$

$$ \dfrac{} {{\langle (\texttt{Closure} (\rho', e)) v_2, \rho \rangle \to \langle e, \texttt{bind} (\rho', v_2) \rangle}}\quad\text{(APPLY-3)}$$

Where `bind` adds $v_2$ to the environment, adding it "on top" of the list that represents it.

$$ \dfrac{}{\langle v\, e_2, \rho \rangle \to \bot} \quad\text{(APPLY-KO)} $$

Comment: And what you're trying to prove is true?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I think it should. The rules and interpreter are fairly simple, and I made them side by side. What's your take on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must strengthen the theorem to be proved by induction. In the $e_1e_2$ case, the current induction hypothesis just tells you that $e_1$ reduces to a closure, but not anything more about how the enclosed expression reduces. Another hint that something is missing is that in the $\lambda x . e$ case (and the closure case which is hidden under "values"), you don't make use of the induction hypothesis on $e$, which is precisely about how $e$ reduces.

You will have more luck with a proof by induction on a recursive property like the following:

$P(e) = ``\forall n \rho v,\; \mathcal{E}(n,\rho,e) = v \implies (\rho,e) \to^\star v \wedge (\forall \rho' e',\; v = \mathbf{Closure}(\rho',e') \implies P(e'))"$

This creates new problems that you will have to figure out (Now it's too strong for the case of variables, how to weaken it a bit? Is this recursive property even well-defined? (if not, how to make it so?)). Hopefully this gets the ball rolling for you.

Comment: I'm certain your suggestion is on the right track; I did not manage to complete the proof but I feel like this got me closer. Thanks :)